# I want to create an ordered list with dotted lines, indicating the size of the file. How do?

Tags: jquery, css, templates

Example below:

[image]

ignore the "257 px" and "324 px" !

Thank you!

Comment: If the picture dont open, try: http://i.imgur.com/7Vzpl6r.png

Comment: what have u tried???please send us your code or give us a jsfiddle..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664469/adding-a-dotted-line-spacer-infill-with-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898287/how-to-display-text-a-dotted-line-then-more-text-spanning-the-width-of-the-page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278030/menu-style-fill-in-with-periods, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360830/adding-a-dotted-line-trail-after-menu-description

Comment: The dotted lines in your image are not indicating the file size, they are simply filling the gap between the file size text and the title text.

Comment: @Vector: I think that's just poor grammar. His image explains it better.

Comment: This solution looks great: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17651357/65387

Comment: yes vector,is exactly what I want to do!

Comment: Yes @Mark, sorry my bad english!

Comment: @Romulo, I posted a solution to your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in pure CSS

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/j6JWT/252/

```
dl { width: 400px }
dt { float: left; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap }
dd { float: left; width: 100px; overflow: hidden }

dt span:after { content: " .................................................................................." }
```

**EDITED**

Another solution is by using position absolute, still pure CSS

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/nDNsW/

```
ol {
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    width: 400px;
    position:relative;
     border-bottom: thin black dotted;
    padding:10px 0;
}
.pdf {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:-17px;
}
.one {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:-17px;
}
span {
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:13px;
}
```

Comment: Having the numbers right-aligned usually looks nicer, but Romulo's question doesn't demonstrate which he prefers.

Comment: unfortunately don't work! =/ but thanks !

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle, it does in fact work. Without seeing your exact code there's not a lot else I can do. Good luck in your ventures.

Comment: @Romulo i've added edited my answer with another solution, hope it helps you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

To fill the gaps you'd either have to have some sort of fixed layout, calculate an average width of the characters used in that font, or just use a monospaced font to make sure all characters are the same width. I'll do the latter (using monospace) to show an example of how it's done, and then it's just a matter of figuring out how many periods to insert :

```
var items = {'Big title text here xyxyxyx':'(pdf) 57mb', 
             'Small title text':'(pdf) 57mb'
            },
     ul   = $('<ul />');

$.each(items, function(k,v) {
    var span1 = $('<span />', {text: k}),
        span2 = $('<span />', {text: Array(60 - (k.length+v.length)).join('.')}),
        span3 = $('<span />', {text: v});

    $('<li />').append(span1, span2, span3).appendTo(ul);
});

ul.appendTo('body');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh7A9/1/)

**EDIT:**

Or you could use fake dots like a border : http://jsfiddle.net/Lh7A9/2/

Comment: You don't need a monospaced font. You can use an image for the dots and then cover it up with a solid background.

Comment: @Mark - I've seen your comment above, and the image of the fake dots is one way to go, and it looks fairly simple and is in many cases a great way to solve this, but I was trying to show how you'd insert actual periods, and not an image, and without several elements on top of each other etc. There are ways to estimate width of text etc. but a monospaced font makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Even if you estimated the width of the font, it would be off by a little. You could use real dots and mask those too, but it would be trickier.

Comment: wow, great code, but very complex... but this may give me more work in the future. But thanks very much!

Comment: @RomuloSousa - It's probably easier to understand in a simpler example, like [**THIS ONE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh7A9/3/) ???

Comment: yes, you greatly simplified! Very thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/CLSEY/1/)

No images required, no layering/masking (allows patterned background), no requirement for monospaced fonts.

#### HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title">Big text here</div>
        <div class="dots"></div>
        <div class="value">57 MB</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="title">Small title text</div>
        <div class="dots"></div>
        <div class="value">104 MB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title">One more for good luck</div>
        <div class="dots"></div>
        <div class="value">4.8 MB</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/ps_neutral.png);
}

.row {
    display: table;
}

.title,.dots,.value {
    display: table-cell;
}

.title, .value {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.table {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.dots {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Although you may want to play with the dots a bit, I think they sit a bit too low.

Comment: unfortunately  don't work! but thanks!

Comment: @RomuloSousa: Can you elaborate on why it doesn't work?

Comment: @RomuloSousa, as you can see from the jsFiddle, it is demonstrated as working. Usually it is best to avoid the phrase "it doesn't work" entirely, and just explain what problem you _are_ having.